# Perl LibXML tidy HTML

Tags: perl, libxml2

I have this HTML snippet in the file: 1.html:

```html
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head>
<body>
abash
<div>a·bash·ment</span>
<h6>1</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code above, the tags are not matched(`<div>` and `</span>`). I wrote the following XML::LibXML codes to correct and tidy the tags:

```
use 5.31.3;
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use XML::LibXML;
use utf8::all;
open(my $FH, ">:encoding(UTF-8)", "2.html") or die "Can't open '1.html': $!";
@ARGV = "1.html";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
$parser->recover(1); 
say $FH $parser->parse_html_string(join "", <>)->toStringHTML();
```

The results is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body>
abash
<div>aÂ·bashÂ·ment
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the content of `div` tag is not showing properly, which should be the same as the original `a·bash·ment`. I guess this should be an encoding issue.  I'm not sure where to change the encoding settings. Does someone run into this issue before?

Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you requiring 5.31.3? It's really odd to require a dev version unless it fixes some specific bug that affects your code. The code you posted doesn't even require anything newer than 5.8!

Comment: Tip: Note that `use 5.12.0;` and higher implies `use strict;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation copied below, `toStringHTML` produces an encoded byte string, so you shouldn't be encoding it again. Replace

```
open(my $FH, ">:encoding(UTF-8)", "2.html")
```

with

```
open(my $FH, ">:raw", "2.html")
```

---

> **toStringHTML**
>
> ```
> $str = $document->toStringHTML();
> ```
>
> *toStringHTML* serialize the tree to a byte string in the document encoding as HTML. With this method indenting is automatic and managed by libxml2 internally.